# Here is an extra ")" in my laravel project which laravel queries for me

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

Here are my codes:

```php
DB::table('admins')->whereIn('a_id', function ($query)
        {
            $query->select('a_id')->fromRaw('( select a_id, row_number() over(
            partition by a_username order by a_username) as row_num from admins
            ) t')
                ->whereRaw('row_num > 1');
        })->delete();
});
```

Here is what laravel query for me:

```
delete from `admins` where `a_id` in 
(select `a_id` from ( select a_id, row_number() over(
partition by a_username order by a_username) as row_num from admins ) 
t where row_num > 1));
```

As you can see there is a ")" at the end of the query and if I remove it It will work but how can I do that??

I got that from this error :

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of 
GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is 
illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: delete from `admins` 
where 
`a_id` in (select `a_id` from ( select a_id, row_number() over( 
partition by a_username order by a_username) as row_num from admins ) 
t where row_num > 1))
```

With this error I got that here is an extra ")" at the end of the query and It isn't of my codes and it seems laravel put it wrong.

Who knows how can I remove it or if the problem is in codes what mistake did I do in my codes.

My laravel version is: 7.9.2 and My PHP version is 7.4.5 .

Comment: Try changing `strict => true to false` in `config/database.php` in `connections => mysql`. Check if it helps.

Comment: Can you accept the answer for others to get help from ?

Comment: See my answer below click on the tick icon ✔ and also click the up arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
 strict => true to false in config/database.php in connections => mysql.
```

Check if it helps.